# Unsuccessful POST request handling

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
<form method="POST" action="/profile">
    <input name="name" type="text"><br/>
    <input name="password" type="password"><br/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I am trying to send a POST request to a node.js file using this form
And to process the request I did the following after creating the server :

```
if (request.method === 'POST') {
    var data = '', dataFull;
    request.on('data', function (chunk) {
        data += chunk;
    }).on('end', function () {
        dataFull = queryString.parse(data);
    });
    console.log(dataFull);
}
```

But the console just logs undefined instead of logging the object.
And tried logging the data variable but it logged nothing

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: is the given js code in your server side? Why dont you use req.body for getting the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `dataFull` variable is not populated by the time you reach the `console.log(dataFull)` statement. The callbacks you bind on the `data` and `end` are asynchronous and are only fired when the respected events occur. Checkout [this link](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/async%20%26%20performance/ch2.md#you-dont-know-js-async--performance) to learn more about async callbacks (and lot more).
As far as the code is concerned, you can do something like this,

```
if (request.method === 'POST') {
  let data = '';
  request.on('data', function (chunk) {
    data += chunk;

    // Too much POST data, kill the connection!
    // someone can kill node by uploading an endless file! 
    // 1e6 === 1 * Math.pow(10, 6) === 1 * 1000000 ~~~ 1MB
    if(data.length > 1e6){
      request.connection.destroy();
    }
  }).on('end', function () {
    let dataFull = queryString.parse(data);
    console.log(dataFull);
    //- now you can access the fields as dataFull['name'] etc.
    //- maybe call a callback or resolve a promise here
    //- cb(null, dataFull) or resolve(dataFull)
  });
}
```

P.S. Body nuking example taken from [this SO answer and it's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4310087/6611700)

Comment: I already know about this asynchronous stuff but really don't know how I fell to such mistake!!!!